# How can I get an image to be in front of the background color?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have two background colors. One part is grey and the other one is white. The grey part of the background only covers a little part of the background, and rest is covered by white. Now I want to add an image as my 'logo', which should be on the grey part of the background. The image is currently underneath both backgrounds, and I just can't figure out how to get the image to be in front of the backgrounds.

```
<style type="text/css">      
  #grey-bg {
    position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25%;
      background-color: grey;
  }
  body
  {
    background-color:white;
  }   
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="grey-bg">
<body bgcolor="grey">
</div>
<center><img    src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110818145752/prototype/images/thumb/6/64/Prototype_-_Logo.png/660px-Prototype_-_Logo.png alt="Prototype"></center>
```

I hope this is understandable. I am quite new to this, and tried to be as as clear as I could.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Yep, learn the basics first :) you have now two body tags etc..

Comment: I checked out your profile. You should know this. Do you know the answer to this?! :)

Comment: You know that with CSS3 you can have multiple backgrounds on 1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the image element inside the div with the gray background.

```
<div id="grey-bg">    
  <center><img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110818145752/prototype/images/thumb/6/64/Prototype_-_Logo.png/660px-Prototype_-_Logo.png" alt="Prototype" /></center>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LcDTS/

You should also avoid the `center` tag and use CSS instead.